# Too many query rows: 50001 in process builder?

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits

I am getting a Limitexception from the processbuilder, when updating a single Opportunity. The only thing which happens in my Process is that the Owner and one field is being updated by values of the Account.

I have no idea where this error comes from, the result in the E-Mail just says "records, which met the criteria, could not be updated".

Does anyone have an idea what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: Could be nothing to do with your process other than that it triggers other triggers or automation that is causing this issue.

Comment: check for the recursive trigger or in trigger check the query with no limit.

Comment: Tushar almost has it right. You have a record lookup or fast lookup that has incorrect filters applied to it, so you're causing your flow to query too many records (my instincts tell me it's the Account lookup). Make sure that your variables are set correctly and that you're filtering for accounts correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look further than the update of 1 opportunity. Potentially the update of your oppy triggers an update on other (related) records.

Check if you find any workflows/triggers that could execute when updating your oppy.

Comment: Yeah you are right, had nothing to do with the process